# Why is the duplicate close banner strange on this question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003552/initializing-on-declaration-vs-initializing-in-constructors) looks like this right now:

[image]

Notably, the place where the duplicate questions are *usually* listed is empty (leading to a rather awkward "This question already has answers here:" followed by nothing. And it looks like the *real* duplicate was edited directly into the question body.

Why did this happen? Should it be fixed? And if so, how should we go about fixing it?